# Excel #NAME? error with IFNA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Strange behavior in Excel 2016 running on Windows 7.

Please refer to the screenshots below:
In Pic 1, the cell in red box shows #NAME? error.  When I click "Enable Editing" on top, you can see in Pic 2, the cell shows value.  Pic 3 shows the formula I'm using for this cell.

Additional information: I have multiple copies of this excel file, filled with different information.  Only a few of them show this error, others display the value with no problem.

My question is, what causes this and how I can fix it?

**Pic 1:**

[image]

**Pic 2:**

[image]

**Pic 3:**

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner My question is, what causes this and how I can fix it? Thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: Are some workbooks old-style .XLS? The IFNA was introduced with Excel 2013. I don't believe you can use newer .XLSX functions in an .XLS but I haven't checked.

Comment: @Jeeped The file are all .xlsm, Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet.

Comment: Well, I won't ask you if all of the workbooks are being opened in xl2013 or xl2016 but I will recommend that you switch the IFNA to an IFERROR. The IFNA never made much sense to me anyways; it's only good to isolate errors that are not #N/A.

Comment: @Jeeped I think I found the issue after your initial comment.  The ones that's error, were opened and saved in 2010. If you could, please post your comment as answer, I'll accept it after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IFNA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461) function was introduced with Excel 2013. If the workbooks are being opened on computers using Excel 2010 (or earlier) the function will not work and produce a `#NAME?` error as Excel 2010 (or earlier) does not have IFNA as a native function. Further, if the workbooks are saved in Excel 2010 (or earlier), the `#NAME?` remains and will be displayed for Excel 2013 and 2016 users.

Switch to the [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) function which was introduced with Excel 2007 to provide wider compatibility. For the purposes of offering a default value in the case of no match to the lookup, they operate exactly the same way. The IFNA is only useful to isolate errors that are **not** `#N/A`.